# Extract value from string stored as key value pair

Tags: mysql, trim

I have a column that stores value for Owner attribute. The column type is *LONGTEXT*.

For example, userkey1:Rank,userkey2:Rank.....

```
{"1":1,"15607":1,"1345":2}
```

I need to get the userkeys with only rank 1.

I tried something like below.

```
select distinct TRIM('"' from ( TRIM('{' from SUBSTRING_INDEX(attribute_value,':1',1)
```

This works only if the :1 is stored as first entry from the left. It will break if the ":1" is at any other position.

Is there a way to extract the userkey(s) only if the corresponding rank is 1 irrespective of the position in the string?

Comment: This is virtually identical to the question you asked yesterday. Please don't repost questions. Sometimes it will take some time to be answered. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers for other tips.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Understood. I thought i will use this post to check if there is alternate way to get this output using non-json functions.